# Upload meta with a presigned put object link on Minio

Tags: node.js, pre-signed-url, minio

I have an endpoint that uses the nodejs client of minio to generate a pre-signed URL.

```
client.presignedPutObject('my_bucket', 'my_object', 24 * 60 *60 , (err, url) => {});
```

When I use the URL to upload a file using curl it works.

```
curl -X "PUT" "http://127.0.0.1:9000/uploads/f72cd073-b0f5-4ca7-9d34-73c5199a85a3?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=Q3AM3UQ867SPQQA43P2F%2F20200610%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200610T195808Z&X-Amz-Expires=30&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=5fa4ad5fc550d0418a6087782695d5e805449518e87a9d9314ce91d161193d54 \
 -H 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream'
```

But I also want to upload some extra metadata.

When I add a x-amz-meta-foo header to the request the request fails because the signature does not match

Request:

```
curl -X "PUT" "http://127.0.0.1:9000/uploads/f72cd073-b0f5-4ca7-9d34-73c5199a85a3?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=Q3AM3UQ867SPQQA43P2F%2F20200610%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200610T195808Z&X-Amz-Expires=30&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=5fa4ad5fc550d0418a6087782695d5e805449518e87a9d9314ce91d161193d54&x-amz-meta-foo=bar" \
 -H 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream'
```

Response:

```
<Error>
  <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
  <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
  <Key>f72cd073-b0f5-4ca7-9d34-73c5199a85a3</Key>
  <BucketName>uploads</BucketName>
  <Resource>/uploads/f72cd073-b0f5-4ca7-9d34-73c5199a85a3</Resource>
  <RequestId>1617470A098B126C</RequestId>
  <HostId>70ed9ca4-79ec-4b45-9631-6ddefe2a3ede</HostId>
</Error>
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

using minio nodejs client 7.0.16
and minio 2020-06-03T22:13:49Z

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `SignatureDoesNotMatch` error because the headers you used when generating the pre-signed URL should match the headers you are using in the request. The meaning is that if you are using the header `x-amz-meta-foo` in the request, you should use this header when generating the pre-signed URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
// node server
app.post('/presign_upload', async (req, res) => {
  // when browser request a presigned_upload_url, it should tell server which file(the file's name) it will upload
  const filename = req.filename;
  const objectid = crypto.randomUUID();
  // you can add other metadata as if the key startsWith 'x-amz-meta-'
  const url = await minio.presignedUrl('PUT', 'abcd', objectid , 600, { 'x-amz-meta-filename': filename });
  res.json({ objectid, put_url });
})

// browser client
const {objectid, put_url} = (await axios.post('/presign_upload', {filename: file.name})).data;
await fetch(put_url, { method: 'put', body: file }); // just upload the file after you got the presigned_upload_url, no need to do any other thing

// node server
minio
  .listenBucketNotification('abcd', '', '', ['s3:ObjectCreated:*'])
  .addListener('notification', async record => {
    // when browser upload complete, this function will be called
    // userMetadata will have filename
    console.log(record, record.s3.object.userMetadata);
  });
```

This anwser is for minio js sdk `7.1.3`